# How to automatically preselect (not just set the value) billing_state dropdown list to be the same as shipping_state dropdown list

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I looked all over on google, I guess I just don't know what to search for because I'm looking to do something relatively simple. I try to only ask questions on here if I am not able to find answers online.

I am looking for the answer in plain JavaScript. I don't want to use jQuery.

You know how when you are filling out a form online to check out, you can click an option that says "check this box if your billing information is the same as your shipping information" and then when you click the box, the billing information automatically gets populated with the shipping information.

I am able to get all input type texts to work properly, but I can't seem to get the drop down select box for the billing_state to be the same as the one that has already been selected for the shipping_state.

I am using all the states. The following is just to simplify the example.

I have a checkbox with an `onchange="setBillingAddress(this)"` and I am using an if statement to check to see if the box is checked. So all that works perfectly.

I am able to get the billing_state dropdown value that was set in the shipping_state to be highlighted in the billing_state dropdown list (you can only see that it's value was set to the value that was in the shipping_state dropdown list after you click the dropdown list). I want it so that it preselects and displays the state without having to click "choose state".

My question is, what do I put inside of the `setBillingAddress()` function to get the billing_state to be preselected and shown to the user so they don't have to see another dropdown box that says "select state" even though the value has already been set.

I have two drop down menus. One named shipping_state with an id of shipping_state and the other named billing_state with an id of billing_state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "change" event handler on your billing address, and in the handler, set the selected index of the shipping address to match the selected index of the billing address (assuming everything in your select list matches, which it should).  See it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4AcjD/10/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="billing">
<p>Billing:</p>
<select name="billingState" id="billingState">
    <option>Alabama</option>             
    <option>Alaska</option>                 
    <option>Arizona</option>
    <!-- etc -->
</select>
</div>

<div id="shipping">
<p>Shipping:</p>
<select name="shippingState" id="shippingState">
    <option>Alabama</option>             
    <option>Alaska</option>                 
    <option>Arizona</option>
    <!-- etc -->
</select>
</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
var billingState = document.getElementById( "billingState" );
var shippingState = document.getElementById( "shippingState" );
billingState.addEventListener( "change", 
    function() { 
        shippingState.selectedIndex = billingState.selectedIndex;
    } );
```

Comment: This seems to be missing the javascript. Maybe you forgot to resave your fiddle? You should post your code in your answer too. Fiddle's die and we want others to benefit from your knowledge.

Comment: Correct you are, I neglected to resave.  That's been corrected, and now I'm going to update the question.  Thanks for the heads-up, @mrtsherman

Comment: Hey I went to that link that you left but the javascript portion is missing for some reason? Perhaps someone else went to the page and removed it and then clicked update and forgot to put it back when they themselves were testing it?

Comment: Hi, @user1152406, I updated the jsfiddle...I've been having a lot of trouble with jsfiddle lately not saving the scripts when I think it had.  Anyway, it seems to be working now.

Comment: That is really odd, for some reason the js isn't being shown in the jsfiddle. But then I copied and pasted your javascript from your post here into the jsfiddle and then clicked update and it didn't work. Is there something you have to do in jsfiddle that I am missing? Never used it before! Thank you so much! Jordan

Comment: Huh...I have no idea what's going on.  It doesn't seem to be saving the JSFiddle...let me um...fiddle with it & see if I can fix it.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now.  Every time you save a new version of your JSFiddle, it appends a new number to the end of the URL, and that's what I was missing.  I updated it in the answer above.  Here's the correct URL: http://jsfiddle.net/4AcjD/10/

Comment: ohhhhh!!! Now it works :-)!!!! Ok, now I have a problem. Two beautiful answers, and I am only able to select one. This kills me! Because I want to select both answers as a selected answer. But like Ethan Brown said, I am going to have to read up about Stack Overflow to learn more on how they work. Thank so much for your answer! I really really appreciate it. It is going to take me a little while to decide which answer is going to be selected as accepted. I want to make sure the answer I select benefits the most amount of people.

Comment: I wouldn't fret too much about it...when it comes to answers, you win some and you lose some.  However, if you like my answer, feel free to up-vote it!

Comment: Thanks! I just upvoted both! I didn't even think about doing that to the other posts that I have made. It looks like I am going to be going back through them like Ethan suggested and selecting the accepted answers and upvoting them. Just getting started w/ stack overflow. Awesome website!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the value of one `select` equal to the other. You may want to go through some of your old questions and accept answers.

http://jsfiddle.net/pZZQt/

```
function setBillingAddress(elem) {
    document.getElementById('billing_state').value = elem.value;
}​
```

Comment: I may have the missed the mark here, was just rereading your question. It's really long and a bit hard to follow. Are you asking how you can have the value be the same without using the `onchange` event? So when you tick the checkbox it sets one to the other?

Comment: Hey thank you so much! I copied and pasted your example and it worked perfectly. However in my example, I am looking to have a checkbox clicked that says "same as shipping", and then once the checkbox is clicked, it will then set the billing state to equal the shipping state. Also, both select dropdown menus need to have two different names incase the billing state is different than the shipping state. So that won't work exactly as shown for what I need. Thanks for letting me know about accepting the answers. I had no idea how to do it until today. I realize you have to click the checkbox lol.

Comment: Basically the same answer. Just add a change handler to the checkbox that does the same thing. http://jsfiddle.net/pZZQt/1/

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked. But now I am having a conflicting problem with a css class that isn't auto displaying the billing state because it is using a css class that is conflicting. I found out because if I remove the css class it works perfectly!!!!! But I don't expect anyone in js to be able to solve that problem lol Also, is it possible to accept more than one answer on stack overflow???

Comment: Glad that worked for you. No, you cannot accept multiple answers. If you have questions on how SO works then you should search for them on http://meta.stackoverflow.com. You can read more about why multiple answers cannot be accepted here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable

Comment: Thank you so much Mrtsherman! It was very difficult to decide on which answer to accept. I am going to need to read those links on the meta that you left for me once I get some more time. Right now I am pressed for time so it is not possible. Also, once I have some more time I will go through the other posts and accept the answers and upvote the ones that are good. Thanks so much again!